# Difference between local and hosted version of jQuery / jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Before I used hosted version of headers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

as it is recommended by [Download jQuery mobile page](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

Today I was trying to get local version of headers:

1. Download http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.zip.
2. Download http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js.
3. Uncompress first one and put all files to jQuery folder.
4. Then change meta area for my index.html:

Expected the same UI look&feel at least.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, has no theming - index.html appeared with minimum formatting  (guess no CSS applied).
What's wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that the files are being included?

Comment: Where have you placed `/images/`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering on all questions - content of my target folder the following:

```
.:
images
index.html
jQuery
utils

./images:
post-logo-notitle-1.png
post-logo-notitle-2.png
post-logo-title-blue-1.png
post-logo-title-blue-2.png

./jQuery:
images
index.html
jquery-1.9.1.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.map
jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css
jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css
jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css
jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css

./jQuery/images:
ajax-loader.gif
icons-18-black.png
icons-18-white.png
icons-36-black.png
icons-36-white.png

./utils:
init.js
```

Comment: Ohhh, sorry...
There was no jquery-1.9.1.min.js script. Works fine when changing to "jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"